# Create a Wordpress demo site for plugins showcase

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I'm planning to launch a small marketplace to sell some professional Wordpress plugins and i think it's a good idea to give the opportunity to try my software before buying it.

How can i implement a good demo Wordpress installation with my plugins showcase installed? Which are the best practices? Through my plugins you can insert a lot of data; what's the best way to keep my demo site clean and secure?

Thank you in advance!
Nicola

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a dummy website at demo.yourdomain.com with the plugins installed. If it's a plugin that requires the backend of Wordpress, you can put in some kind of refresh script that puts back the original settings of the website every X time. This way griefers don't get a change to break your dummy site for too long.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah I think this is the best solution; I thought to set a cronjob to erase all db datas that runs every hour and i hope that this keep safe my Wordpress install from spammers and  crackers :)